# Acces to a specific string in list Python to separate in diffent columns

Tags: python, list, csv

I want to separate the values of names in a list into a 3 different columns.
I have this code

```
with open(argv[1],"r") as csvdata:

reader = csv.DictReader(csvdata, delimiter = ",")

#Iterate to each column
for row in reader:

    name = row['name'].split()
    house = row['house']
    birth = row['birth']
```

When I print the value "name"  I have this result:

```
['Adelaide', 'Murton']
['Adrian', 'Pucey']
['Anthony', 'Goldstein']
['Dean', 'Thomas']
['Draco', 'Lucius', 'Malfoy']
['Ernest', 'Macmillan']
['Ginevra', 'Molly', 'Weasley']
['Gregory', 'Goyle']
```

Now my main issue is that I don't know how can I split this values putting the results into 3 different columns of first,middle and last name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This addresses the problem of dealing with strings containing either two words or three words:

```
def get_names(name):
    names = name.split()
    if len(names) == 2:
        return [names[0], '', names[1]]
    else:
        return names

print(get_names('Adelaide Murton'))
print(get_names('Draco Lucius Malfoy'))
```

Running the above code generates this output:

```
['Adelaide', '', 'Murton']
['Draco', 'Lucius', 'Malfoy']
```

Note, however, that this will NOT work if the data contains names like Johannes Diderik van der Waals :)

Answer (score 0):

I find these manipulations to be easier in `pandas`;

```
import pandas, numpy 

csv = pandas.read_csv(arg[1])

def split_name(input_string):
    names = input_string.split()

    if len(names) == 2:
        first = names[0]
        last = names[1]
        middle = numpy.NaN
    elif len(names) == 3:
        first, middle, last = names

    return pandas.Series(first, middle, last)

csv[['first_name', 'middle_name', 'last_name']] = csv.pop('name').map(split_name)
```

Comment: Yep, that's true! but unfornately i can't use pandas lib to this problem because is an exercice in a course with csv library for creating a SQL table. :(

Comment: i gave you another answer with csv, but I am not sure it works.

Comment: I'm tryinf to implement now but i don't know which is the variable "r" you code with next()

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so with csv;

```
import csv 

with open(argv[1],"r") as csvdata:

    reader = csv.DictReader(csvdata, delimiter = ",")

    # placeholder for the modified rows
    final_rows = []

    # catch row 0 as header
    header = reader.next()

    # append the new columns to the header 
    header.append(['first_name', 'middle_name', 'last_name'])

    final_rows.append(header)

    #Iterate to each column
    for row in reader:
        name = row['name'].split()

        # some logic to get the first, middle and last name
        if len(name) == 2:
            first, last = name
            middle = None
        if len(name) == 3:
            first, middle, last = name

        # I'm not sure if it works this way 
        row['first_name'], row['middle_name'], row['last_name'] = first, middle, last

        house = row['house']
        birth = row['birth']

        final_rows.append(row)
```

You can now save `final_rows` to a new `.csv` or continue modifying it. (Like deleting the `name` columns)

Comment: Thanks !!  I understood the logic of creating the columns using those concepts. it works thanks a lot !!